# leafletjs map Interactive Choropleth Map

Tags: dictionary, interactive, choropleth

i'm using leaflet js Choropleth map  : 
https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

what i'm trying to do  on click at (california ) area  load form  databeas all loaction (lat,long) that in same area ??

Answer (score 0):

Since the Choropleth Map is a GeoJson with a collection of polygons, I would go about and use this library `https://github.com/hayeswise/Leaflet.PointInPolygon` to determine if a given location is in the given polygon or not.